# Sum row of list of dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes. Each dataframe is a Stock quote whose row names are dates and column names are buy price, sell price, shares and PL.

I want to obtain a column that contains the percentage of every positive PL contribution to the total daily PL.

Making it simplier. I have the following Data:

```
mylist= structure(list(`1` = structure(list(ID = c(35L, '2009-01-03', '2009-01-04', '2009-01-05'), Income = c(100, 200, 300, 400)), .Names = c("Date", "Income"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(ID = c('2009-01-02', '2009-01-03', '2009-01-04', '2009-01-05'), Income = c(500, -600, 700, 800)), .Names = c("Date", "Income"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), `3` = structure(list(ID = c('2009-01-02', '2009-01-03', '2009-01-04'), Income = c(100, 200, 300)), .Names = c("Date", "Income"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L), class = "data.frame")))
```

Which looks like this:

```
$`1`
        Date Income
1 2009-01-01    100
2 2009-01-03    200
3 2009-01-04    300
4 2009-01-05    400

$`2`
        Date Income
1 2009-01-02    500
2 2009-01-03   -600
3 2009-01-04    700
4 2009-01-05    800

$`3`
        Date Income
1 2009-01-02    100
2 2009-01-03    200
3 2009-01-04    300
```

I want to obtain something that looks like this:

```
$`1`
        Date Income Perc
1 2009-01-03    100 1.00
2 2009-01-03    200 0.20
3 2009-01-04    300 0.23
4 2009-01-05    400 0.33

$`2`
        Date Income  Perc
1 2009-01-02    500  0.83
2 2009-01-03    600 -1.50
3 2009-01-04    700  0.54
4 2009-01-05    800  0.67

$`3`
        Date Income Perc
1 2009-01-02    100 0.17
2 2009-01-03    200 0.20
3 2009-01-04    300 0.23
```

Comment: Your title and description is somewhat confusing.  If you can show a small example with expected ouptut, it would greatly help (`lapply(lst1, rowSums)`

Comment: (1) The data is going to be much easier to handle if you combine it in one data frame and use an ID column to identify each stock. You can then use the `dplyr` package's functions `group_by` and `mutate` to calculate each stocks contribution.
(2) I am not sure I completely understand the impact of negative P/L. Please check the numbers in the two tables and, provide an example for a single day.

Comment: This is a sample of the data. There are lots of columns and dataframes,so I can't use a single DF. if it is negative, just dont add it in the denominator.

Comment: As mentioned above the sample data does not match the output. -600 becomes 600 and the dates in the first data frame don't match. Also the data.frame generated by your code does not match the displayed data (35L). Why can't you combine the data into one data frame? R can handle millions of rows. If you can somehow split the data by month or year and create data frames for separate periods you can get a results with a few lines of code.

Comment: If you had a data frame with a `share` column you could use `my_df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Perc = Income/sum(Income[Income > 0]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions for your problem. I highly recommend combining your data frame in one master data frame in order to reduce the complexity of the code if at all possible. I am sure there are better solutions to the "Separate Data Frame" problem, but most of them will involve multiple loops and thus negatively impact performance.

**Data**

```
mylist= structure(list(`1` = structure(list(ID = c('2009-01-02', '2009-01-03', '2009-01-04', '2009-01-05'), Income = c(100, 200, 300, 400)), .Names = c("Date", "Income"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(ID = c('2009-01-02', '2009-01-03', '2009-01-04', '2009-01-05'), Income = c(500, -600, 700, 800)), .Names = c("Date", "Income"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "data.frame"), `3` = structure(list(ID = c('2009-01-02', '2009-01-03', '2009-01-04'), Income = c(100, 200, 300)), .Names = c("Date", "Income"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L), class = "data.frame")))
```

**Combined Data Frame**

```
library(dplyr)

# add an ID to each data frame
for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
  mylist[[i]] <- cbind(mylist[[i]], stock_id = names(mylist)[i])
}

# create data frame with all observations
my_data_frame <- do.call(rbind, mylist)
rownames(my_data_frame) <- NULL

my_data_frame %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(Perc = Income/sum(Income[Income > 0]))
```

```
# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   Date [4]
   Date       Income stock_id   Perc
   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 2009-01-02    100 1         0.143
 2 2009-01-03    200 1         0.5  
 3 2009-01-04    300 1         0.231
 4 2009-01-05    400 1         0.333
 5 2009-01-02    500 2         0.714
 6 2009-01-03   -600 2        -1.5  
 7 2009-01-04    700 2         0.538
 8 2009-01-05    800 2         0.667
 9 2009-01-02    100 3         0.143
10 2009-01-03    200 3         0.5  
11 2009-01-04    300 3         0.231
```

**Separate Data Frames**

```
library(dplyr)

all_dates <- unique(unlist(lapply(mylist, function(x) unique(x$Date))))

for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
  mylist[[i]] <- cbind(mylist[[i]], stock_id = names(mylist)[i])
}

perc_all <- list()
for(i in 1:length(all_dates)){
  temporary <- lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x$Date == all_dates[i], ])
  all_obs_date <- do.call(rbind, temporary)
  all_obs_date$Perc <- all_obs_date$Income/sum(all_obs_date$Income[all_obs_date$Income > 0])
  perc_all[[i]] <- all_obs_date
}
perc_final <- do.call(rbind, perc_all)
lapply(mylist, function(x) {
  left_join(x, perc_final) %>% select(-stock_id)
})
```

```
$`1`
        Date Income      Perc
1 2009-01-02    100 0.1428571
2 2009-01-03    200 0.5000000
3 2009-01-04    300 0.2307692
4 2009-01-05    400 0.3333333

$`2`
        Date Income       Perc
1 2009-01-02    500  0.7142857
2 2009-01-03   -600 -1.5000000
3 2009-01-04    700  0.5384615
4 2009-01-05    800  0.6666667

$`3`
        Date Income      Perc
1 2009-01-02    100 0.1428571
2 2009-01-03    200 0.5000000
3 2009-01-04    300 0.2307692
```